# Poolboy example with DBConnection

Tags: elixir

I can't figure out how to use pooling with database connection handled directly (without `Ecto`).

For instance: [Oracle driver for elixir](https://hexdocs.pm/jamdb_oracle/Jamdb.Oracle.html) says it can use pooling through [DBConnection](https://hexdocs.pm/db_connection/1.1.3/DBConnection.html), but an example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct to suppose that there aren't example on the Internet because it is as easy as adding a:

```
[pool: DbConnection.PoolBoy]
```

keyword in the `start_link` opts?

So if I find troubles is the Adapter library which maybe doesn't implement the feature?